# Why I can return a reference of a value which not lives long enough?

Tags: rust

I return a reference of a temporary value from `some` function. I'm not expecting this to compile successfully, however, I got no warning or error and the program works well.

```
struct A {
    pub a: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let b = A { a: 5 };
    let a = some(&b);
    println!("{}", a.a);
}

fn some(_: &A) -> &A {
    &A { a: 14 }
}
```

`impl Drop for A` or return `&mut A` will cause this program cannot compile.
I am using `rustc 1.35.0-nightly`.

Is this problem caused by some optimization? Why will optimization lead to this "grammar feature"?

Comment: I hope the duplicate resolves your question. If not, feel free to edit your question and ping me.